# Inkscape: animated SVG to video?

Tags: video, svg, inkscape

i created an animated presentation with the [Sozi](http://sozi.baierouge.fr/wiki/en:welcome) plugin for Inkscape. It looks great, however, not all browsers support SVG animations (Chrome for instance does not like the Inkscape/Sozi SVGs at all). 
I would like to convert the presentation to a video. One option would be to do a screen capture, but I am hoping for something better.

Looking around, I also came across [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie) - but creating frame by frame SVGs is not really feasible, as I would like to keep the zooming/sliding animations.

Any ideas of what tool to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export SVG animated with javascript to movie format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652905/how-to-export-svg-animated-with-javascript-to-movie-format)

Answer (score 8):

There is a node package called `timecut` which uses Chromium to record an SVG into an MP4 video file. https://github.com/tungs/timecut

## Installation

```
$ cd project
$ npm install timecut
```

## Usage

```
$ cd project
$ ./node_modules/timecut/cli.js Animation.svg
```

This creates a file named `video.mp4`.

`timecut` has quite a number of options, like frame rate, pixel format, etc.

Answer (score 7):

### 1. Convert SVG to Canvas

SVG can be converted onto a canvas element using [this tool](http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/)

### 2. Record Canvas Animation

A video file can be created from a canvas animation that using MediaStreamRecorder(depending on browser support) or with [Whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy). 
I have used whammy before, It worked like a charm.

---

Comment: Can you provide a sample code pen of how you were able to record svg content ?  here is what i am trying using recordRTC http://codepen.io/rudi8292/pen/yJEAbd

Answer (score 0):

You may try synfig studio, I've been using it for several personal animation projects. I'ts really nice, with good tutos / documentation / community.

http://www.synfig.org/cms/

quote :
"Synfig Studio is a free and open-source 2D animation software, designed as powerful industrial-strength solution for creating film-quality animation using a vector and bitmap artwork. It eliminates the need to create animation frame-by frame, allowing you to produce 2D animation of a higher quality with fewer people and resources. Synfig Studio is available for Windows, Linux and MacOS X."

hope this helps

Philippe

Answer (score -2):

What you ask is impossible, because SVG animation is interpolated, whereas the major video formats are all frame-based. If you want to render to video, you *have* to separate out discrete frames.

If you expect your users will view the video at the same speed (as opposed to slowing it down), it is good enough to pick a frame-rate high enough to display the animation smoothly (say 30 fps). The disadvantage is of course increased file size.

[Convert animated SVG to movie](https://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie) provides several options for splitting and converting.

---

Incidentally, Chrome does support SVG animation. Have you tried it in a recent version? Also, try exporting your file from Inkscape as a "plain SVG" (instead of the default "Inkscape SVG"), which strips Inkscape-specific elements that could potentially confuse browsers.