# Are there any ways to convert a SVG progressive draw to a video?

Tags: javascript, svg

I've created an web app that client can upload an svg file, the app will create a progressive draw animation from that file, and then create a downloadable video from that animation.

I'm using [Progressive Draw - SVG](http://codecanyon.net/item/progressive-draw-svg/12631997) for the progressive draw animation.

Are there any ways to convert this to an video file or just record this in the screen to render a video file? I was using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording) to record the animation but it seems that this can't record the SVG format as the video is all blank.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If canvas works (apparently), have you tried to convert SVG to Canvas first?

Comment: You can find infos here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818670/inkscape-animated-svg-to-video

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried but this is the drawing animation of a standing still SVG file, not an animation one. Ex: [This](http://svg-draw.hoatam.us/?first=fb-sketch-video-dispatcher-combo) is the link of the drawing animation of [this](http://svg-draw.hoatam.us/svgs/fb-sketch-video-dispatcher-combo.svg) file.