# How to export SVG animated with javascript to movie format?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, video

I've been making animations with a library called [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/), this library uses *javascript* and [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to animate SVG elements instead of the supplied [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) `<animate>` tag.

Is there a way to convert the contents of an `<svg>` tag into a bitmap image **60 frames per second** over the extent of an animation? Or better yet, compile the calls to **requestAnimationFrame** into a movie?

Libraries like [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) first convert the SVG onto **canvas** which is effectively the same thing, but is this the only way to get a movie file out of a *javascript SVG animation*?

Comment: Within the browser, I  believe that is the case.  I suppose you could also do something like using a [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-page)  script that sends events to the page to advance one frame at a time, taking a screenshot each step using puppeteer's `screenshot()` method.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau hey that’s not a bad idea. I’ll keep you posted and the thread what I come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can always record your screen with eg. [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) playing your SVG in the browser (or whatever you use to play it) and :

1. **Get OBS** from https://obsproject.com/, install it, run and learn how to record your screen. It's easy as hitting the "start recording button" on the right bottom of the app window.
2. **Open your SVG** in your preferred browser or player you use. If possible, make it full screen. Make sure you can restart animation easily - like using CTRL+R to refresh the browser window.
3. Switch to OBS and **start recording** (on Mac OS you can start it from the menu bar).
4. Switch to browser or player and **replay your SVG animation**. Wait for a second after it stops, to have enough gap for editing later.
5. Switch back to OBS and **stop recording**. Video is saved as MP4 - check the quality, if not enough, change OBS settings and try again.